# Вляиет ли вывод статей через ajax на поисковые запросы?

Tags: поиск, ajax, поисковые-системы

Всем доброго времени суток!

Разрабатывается новостная лента на сайте, и встал вопрос о способе вывода статей: через ajax или через POST  с перезагрузкой страницы.
Я за ajax - быстрее(не происходит обновление всех страницы) и современнее.

Но влияет на вывод статей через ajax  на поисковые машины? Т.е. не произойдет ли такой ситуации, что какой не была бы статья уникальной, вывод через ajax  не позволит ей появится в списке на поисковые запросы?

Comment: > через POST с перезагрузкой страницы.

POST существует для обновления данных. POST - неидемпотентный метод.

Comment: я не думаю, что поисковые системы умеют прокручивать страницы для ajax подгрузки контента. Хотя, может и умеют, но как они будут знать, что на странице есть ajax подгрузки новостей? Они проиндексируют то, что увидят при обычной загрузке контента

Comment: Вообще по хорошему нужно использовать Progressive Enhancement при таких разработках, то есть на сайте должен присутствовать POST и поверх него закрываться выводом AJAX'а. В таком случае и индексация роботами сохраняется и Ajax исправно работает, но думаю вы не будете этим заморачиваться, так как это надо проделать две работы вместо одной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Яндекс вебмастер - помощь - [Индексирование AJAX-сайтов](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/robot-workings/ajax-indexing.xml)

Comment: оно же для google и прочих поисковых машин?

Comment: Оно же [для Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992?hl=en) (на англ.)